# Gremlin groupcount by edges and then also select other properties besides the count itself

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server, amazon-neptune

I'm modeling a social network where users follow others. I'm trying to generate a list of potential users to follow and order it by those who are also followed by the people I'm following (let's call these 'mutualFollowers' for lack of a better term).

My current query does this by getting all users who are followed by the users that "myusername" follows (edges "following" from userOne --> userTwo) and removing those who the user "myusername" already follows (the aggregated group "following" here).

```
g.V().has("user", "username", "myusername").out("follows").aggregate("following").out("follows").where(without("following")).groupCount().by("username").order(local).by(values, decr).next()
```

I can correctly generate this list, but I am only able to get a list with entries like

`username: 5` (where username is the username and 5 is the number of mutual followers)

I would also like to be able to select other properties of each user vertex like "name", "profile_pic", etc in some form similar to

```
{username: username, name: personName, mutualFollowers: 10}
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

(using AWS Neptune)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without changing too much you could just `project()` a `Map` as the key in the `groupCount()`:

```
g.V().
  has("user", "username", "myusername").
  out("follows").
  aggregate("following").
  out("follows").
  where(without("following")).
  groupCount().
    by(project('username','name').
         by('username').by('name')).
  order(local).by(values, decr)
```

That doesn't quite get you exactly the form you asked for though but I wanted to demonstrate a way that required the least amount of change to your original query. If you want an actual `mutualFollowers` key in the map you will have to deconstruct your `Map` and flatten it:

```
g.V().
  has("user", "username", "myusername").
  out("follows").
  aggregate("following").
  out("follows").
  where(without("following")).
  groupCount().
  order(local).by(values, decr).
  unfold().
  project('username','name','mutualFollowers').
    by(select('keys').values('username')).
    by(select('keys').values('name')).
    by(select(values))
```

Comment: Thanks! Also thanks for giving both soluations, really made the concept more clear